# Use L'Hôpital's rule to evaluate this limit

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to0} \left(\frac{a^x + b^x}{2}\right)^{1/x}  = (ab)^{1/2}$$
I tried taking logarithm to both sides, but got stuck

I got to

e^ (lim (a^x loga + b^x logb)/(a^x + b^x)

Comment: Does it help if I remind you that $\log p^q = q\log p$?  The argument of the limit operator has $q = 1/x$ and $p=\frac12(a^x+b^x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : Write
$$
f(x) = \left ( \frac{a^x + b^x}{2} \right )^{1/x}
$$
and consider
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \ln f(x)
$$

Comment: +1: this is definitely a very good way to go. Get the $x$ into the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $ \ln \left( \left( \dfrac {a^x+b^x}{2} \right)^{1/x} \right) = \dfrac {1}{x} \cdot \ln \left( \dfrac {a^x+b^x}{2} \right) $.

Now, consider $ \lim \left( \dfrac {\ln \left( \dfrac {a^x+b^x}{2} \right)}{x} \right) $.

The derivative of the numerator is $ \dfrac {a^x \ln a + b^x \ln b}{a^x+b^x} $.

The derivative of the denominator is $ 1 $.

Now, our original limit is just $$ \exp \left( \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \dfrac {a^x \ln a + b^x \ln b}{a^x+b^x} \right) \right). $$

Can you do it from here?

Comment: Isn't the derivative of the numerator

(a^x loga + b^x logb) / (a^x + b^x) ??

Comment: Yes, apologies! I have edited that.

Comment: Could you give me one more hint please? That's the step where I got stuck because I don't know how to get ride of those a^x and b^x. 
And, are you sure about that 2 in the denominator?

Comment: I got it I got it!! Now it's time to take the limit. Jesus... 
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sorry for making two mistakes! Glad you got it now. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I am not missing anything, here is a solution without LH rule, probably you will not see anywhere:

$$\lim _{ x\to 0 } \left( \frac { a^{ x }+b^{ x } }{ 2 }  \right) ^{ 1/x }=\lim _{ x\to 0 } \left( \frac { { \left( a^{ x/2 }-b^{ x/2 } \right)  }^{ 2 }+{ 2\left( ab \right)  }^{ x/2 } }{ 2 }  \right) ^{ 1/x }$$$$=\lim _{ x\to 0 } \left( \frac { { \left( a^{ x/2 }-b^{ x/2 } \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ 2 } +{ \left( ab \right)  }^{ x/2 } \right) ^{ 1/x }\\ =\lim _{ x\to 0 } \left( 0+{ \left( ab \right)  }^{ x/2 } \right) ^{ 1/x }={ \left( ab \right)  }^{ 1/2 }$$

Comment: Interesting. I mainly asked this because I wanted to get the result Ahaan got for the numerator if I use L'Hopital's rule. But it seems I'm missing something. Can you help me with that? Please check the answer Ahaan gave me.

Comment: I have edited mine.